# How to make new polygon/feature from point which is NOT centroid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation

I've spent all morning searching help sites and digging through the FAQs and worksheets but have failed miserably.

I am an ArcGIS novice so I hope this is not too much of a "newbie" question but I'm trying to work out how to make a new polygon/feature from a point which is NOT a centroid?

```
----                ----
| . | <--not this   |   |
----       this-->  .---
```

I have a series of points where the Easting and Northing listed represents the lower left hand corner of a 200m square. I know how to make a circular buffer which I can convert to a square with the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool but this isnt really what I want.

The data is of 3g strengths which is meant to be in grid squares. I cannot upload this file this due to NDA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually changed the eastings and northings tool to move 100m east and north accordingly. Then I used the buffer tool using the new point location as a centroid and turned that into a square.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer, Matthew: it is a creative use of the GIS' capabilities to accomplish your objective.